# How to configure API URL running on localhost on port 8080 in nuxt js?

Tags: rest, api, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the following vue file. My REST API base URL is http://localhost:8080/api/. When I access http://localhost:8080/api/dfc/system/docbases directly, I get the response as shown.

```
["gr_swy","SubWayX_DEMO"]
```

But I want to get the response through nuxt js which is running on http://localhost:3000/restapi/. I tried to follow all the articles, but not able to figure out where I'm doing wrong.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    {{docbases}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from "axios";
  #import axios from "../../.nuxt/axios"; (tried both)

  export default {
    methods: {
      // asyncData({ req, params }) {
      //   return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/dfc/system/docbases")
      //     .then(res => {
      //       return { docbases: res.data };
      //     }).catch((e) => {
      //     error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Not found' })
      //   })
      // },
      async asyncData ({ params }) {
        const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/dfc/system/docbases');
        return { docbases: data }
      }
    },
    head: {
      title: "D2Rest"
    }
  };
</script>
```

My nuxt.config.js is like this: I tried changeOrigin with true and false both. Can you please help me what extra things I need to configure?

```
axios: {
    proxy: true,
  },

  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" },
      changeOrigin: false,
      prependPath: false
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't enable Cross Origin in my java code. I have enabled now and it's resolved.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your configuration, I'm assuming you're using the [Nuxt Axios module](https://axios.nuxtjs.org)...

The problem seems to be that you're importing Axios unnecessarily, thus bypassing your `axios` configuration in `nuxt.config.js`. The [Nuxt Axios module docs](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage#component) describe its usage in components:

```js
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const ip = await $axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
    return { ip }
  }
}
```

Note the destructured parameter `$axios`. Use that parameter instead of importing your own instance of `axios` (i.e., don't do `import axios from 'axios'`), which is not the same as the one configured by Nuxt. No other imports are needed for `$axios`.

#### Proxy URL

Another problem is that your explicitly requesting the proxy address in the URL, but that should be excluded:

```js
// const { data } = await $axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/dfc/system/docbases');  // DON'T DO THIS
const { data } = await $axios.get('/api/dfc/system/docbases');
```

Comment: Thanks! That is working with http://icanhazip.com, but not with this http://localhost:8080/api/dfc/system/docbases. Not sure what's wrong with this, direct url works for me, but not with axios one. What else do I need to add as API URL? Any idea?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/dfc/system/docbases internally uses intranet url, proxy is there

Comment: The problem is you're including the proxy address in the URL. Remove it so that it begins with `/api/` (e.g., `/api/dfc/system/docbases`).

Comment: Then it is taking with localhost:300 and giving 404 error. Yes @nuxtjs/proxy installed.

Comment: The proxy setting works for me in my setup, using the notes in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205655/discussion-between-srivastava-and-tony19).